# Zend Form: Call to a member function setValue() on a non-object

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-form

i have this error:

> Call to a member function setValue() on a non-object in

when i try to populate a form with my storeged data. The think most strange, is that if i use the same method on other forms, it works fine.

My code is:

on zend form abstract:

```
class App_Form_BootstrapForm extends Zend_Form
{

    public function __construct($options = null)
    {
        // decorator style
    }

    public function populate($data)
    {
        foreach ($data as $field => $value) {
            $this->{$field}->setValue($value);
        }
        return $this;
    }
}
```

here my form:

```
class Application_Form_Admin_Pneumatico_Pneumatico extends App_Form_BootstrapForm
{

    public function init()
    {
        $this->setAttrib("vertical", true);

        $this->setMethod('post');
        $this->setName('pneumatico');
        $this->setAction('');
        $this->setAttrib('enctype', 'multipart/form-data');

        $this->addElement('text', 'codice', array(
            'filters' => array('StringTrim'),
            'validators' => array(
                array('StringLength', true, array(3, 50))
            ),
            'required' => true,
            'placeholder' => 'Codice prodotto',
            'class' => 'form-control',
            'label' => 'Codice (*)'
        ));
        // other form elements
    }
}
```

I tryed to pass the form and the value to insert to the view and then use populate, but i had the same error. I tryed to do that in controller before send it to the view, but i get the same error.

Someone can help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your error should be coming from the `populate` function here

```
$this->{$field}->setValue($value);
```

and if one of the keys in that `$data` array is not a form value `$this->{$field}` will cause *non-object* error.

Check all the keys in the data array first.

Comment: Thanks, the problem was in my array `$data`